# What do you call a [part] of a pie chart?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, charts

Irrespective of what the chart is displaying, what is the best term to describe a part/slice/share/portion of a pie chart?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct term is *slice*, fitting the pie metaphor.

Comment: *Slice* is good because it fits the metaphor, but I think it's a little bit whimsical & familiar for, say, a formal business or academic presentation. In those contexts, *segment* and *sector* would be more likely to slot in without calling attention to themselves.

Comment: I don't agree that it is whimsical.  Sector is the correct mathematical term for this sort of part of a circle and is perfectly acceptable.  Anybody using a pie chart in academia is deserving of ridicule. ;)

Comment: Hmm. Pie-charts are beneath the dignity of academia, huh? I can't be bothered to find online content from a redbrick uni to counter that - The Open University has a page on pie-charts that's easy to find. They *are* a bit 'populist', in that they use the word *slice* 4 times as opposed to only 3 *segments*. Maybe the redbricks might reverse that ratio. Maybe you're right anyway. Maybe there's no such thing as 'right' in these subtle distinctions, but I see your rebuttal has 5 upvotes already, so I guess you're at least winning.

Comment: I'll pick this answer, because IMO it bests suits the metaphor of the pie and the way these charts are used than sector.

Anyway, thanks for all the answers

Comment: Tranche is posh and often used in business but maybe its too obvious for... a pie?

Answer (score 6):

Since each "part" is a sector of a circle, sector can be used IMO.

Answer (score 5):

I think the word "segment" would usually be used.

Comment: Isn't [sector](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/circle-sector-segment.html) technically more accurate, at least from mathematical point of view? Though in practice I doubt anyone would object to "segment", in the more general sense of "a piece" rather than the strictly mathematical one :)

Comment: Interetsing -- you're right that geometrically, "sector" is the correct term, yet I think people more often call them segments. I guess they're not using "segment" in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 3):

All the ones mentioned are fine. You can also call it *wedge*, especially with 3D pies.  One that is pulled out is called *exploded wedge*.

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned it, but the first word that came to my mind was "sector".

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to go with *section*.