# Word for a piece of a pie chart?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to name a part of a piechart](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-name-a-part-of-a-piechart)

What is the correct name for a shape which is like a triangle but with one edge circular, like a slice of cake?

Comment: like a slice of pie, even. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a **sector**, 'the shape enclosed between an arc and the two radii at either end of that arc' (Oxford Mathematics Study Dictionary).

Comment: +1 note: non-specialist dictionaries list it, too (http://www.onelook.com/?w=sector)

Answer (score 1):

It's a [sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector).